# (Xcode / Swift) How to hide toolbar when scrolling down UIWebView?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiwebview, toolbar, uitoolbar

I have a **UIWebView** in my **ViewController** and a navigation controller embedded in my **ViewController**. In my navigation controller, I selected **"Show Toolbar"** and **"Hide Bars on Swipe"** but the Toolbar doesn't hide. It only works when **"Show Navigation Bar"** is selected with the Toolbar.

Is there anyway to have the **Toolbar** hide on swipe when scrolling down the **UIWebView**?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` for that.

Here is example code for hide navigation bar and tool bar with scroll:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var webV: UIWebView!
    var lastOffsetY :CGFloat = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webV.scrollView.delegate = self
        let url = "http://apple.com"
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        webV.loadRequest(request)
    }

    //Delegate Methods
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView){
        lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView){

        let hide = scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastOffsetY
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(hide, animated: true)
        toolBar.hidden = hide
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was extremely helpful. I also discovered that it should be 

self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(hide, animated: true)

instead of 

self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(hide, animated: true)

Comment: Happy to help you..:)